# Retrieve a list of parse users in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, runtime-error

So, I'm trying to get the list of usernames from all the parse users and show it inside a listview, so I can search for anyone in my application, but I'm getting this error instead:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.les20162.room8, PID: 19957
              java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                  at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                  at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                  at com.les20162.room8.Activities.RoomatesFragment.initList(RoomatesFragment.java:171)
                  at com.les20162.room8.Activities.RoomatesFragment.onCreateView(RoomatesFragment.java:81)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is the code I'm using to get the users list:

```
public class RoomatesFragment extends Fragment {

//variables
private EditText             search;
private String[]             users;
private ArrayList<String>    listUsers;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView             listView;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public RoomatesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static RoomatesFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    RoomatesFragment fragment = new RoomatesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View myView;
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_roomates, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listviewMoradores);
    search   = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.search);

    initList();

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(charSequence.toString().equals("")){
                initList();
            }
            else{
                searchUser(charSequence.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    return myView;
}

public void searchUser(String userToSearch) {
    for(String user: users){
        if(!user.contains(userToSearch)){
            listUsers.remove(user);
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

private void initList(){
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            users = new String[objects.size()+1];
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    users[i] = objects.get(i).getUsername();
                }
            } else {
                users[0] = "NONE";
            }
        }
    });
    listUsers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(users));
    adapter   = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.user, listUsers);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

I've tryed almost everything but I keep getting the same error, do you guys have any ideas of how can I correct this? I'm very new at android programming so, any help will be welcome :)

P.S: English is not my mother language, so sorry for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

probably try using AsyncTask. you can fetch the list and once done, try to draw. Probably the list doesnt have populated the list and trying to draw it.

Comment: How can I use AsyncTask in this case?